# How to change Oracle Exceptions language in .Net/C#?

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm developping a .Net application that connects to an Oracle database.

In my application, the exceptions are thrown in French which I don't like.

I'm using the following code to change the language but it's unsuccesful.

```
    'Set the language to english
    Dim Glob As OracleGlobalization = OracleGlobalization.GetThreadInfo
    Glob.Language = "AMERICAN"
    OracleGlobalization.SetThreadInfo(Glob)
```

After this code the exceptions are still thrown in French.

Does anyone know how to change the Exceptions Language please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute ALTER SESSION command. Maybe your API has facade methods for it, but it's an ultimate way for everywhere and always. See example:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Dec 11 16:01:02 2014

SQL> conn test/test@soft12c1

Connected.

SQL> alter session set nls_language=french;

Session altered.

SQL> select 1/0 from dual;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: le diviseur est щgal р zщro

SQL> alter session set nls_language=american;

Session altered.

SQL> select 1/0 from dual;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```