# Changing the language of Oracle error messages in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I want to change the language settings to (English) of SQL Developer.

I've tried many things like

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en 
AddVMOption -Duser.country=US
```

And sqldeveloper.conf file

And even I've changed my system language and display settings to English and countries to 
United States. But this error message is not shown as in English. Just this highligted part of this error message is not English. How can change to all display messages to English language?

Thank you. 
[image: Related image]

Related image link:
https://i.hizliresim.com/GDqLl3.png

The interesting thing is even though a lot of message is in English, just the "ORA-01017" message is Turkish. Not all Turkish of this message. Just higlighted part is Turkish :(

Comment: What is the default language of the database? You will probably find that SQL Developer is just displaying the exceptions reported from the database verbatim and it is the database that has a different language.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26972250/1509264

Comment: @MT0 my language of the database is also english. The interesting thing is even though a lot of message is in English, just the "ORA-01017" message is Turkish. Not all Turkish of this message. Just higlighted part is Turkish :(

Comment: Did you try `alter session set nls_language=american;`? (Once you are connected to the database)

Comment: Hi @MT0, it occurs when I try to connect with SQL Developer. So, I haven't connected yet. By the way, I've tried this one by connecting with the system user. And then try to connect with 'sh' user. But, it didn't work. What should I do,

Comment: `ORA-01017: invalid username/password` - use the correct password, unlock the account if it is locked, change the password if you need to (i.e. it has expired).

Comment: What is NLS Lang set to in preferences?

Comment: Hi Mr @thatjeffsmith, I know you. You're product manager of Oracle SQL Developer :) NLS Language: American, Sort: BINARY, Territory: AMERICA, Comparison : BINARY. By the way, glad to see you here. :)

Comment: If you try in sqlplus, what do you see? This is very odd behavior.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith , I get the same result in sqlplus, too. :(